# Styling points with shapes and graduated symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, style

I have a point vector layer based on a .csv file. I am trying to show categorical data (seasons) and continuous data (catch per unit effort, CPUE) at sampling sites that get revisited.

I have used point displacement to account for site revisits, and I have graduated symbology to account for my continuous CPUE data, but now I am having problems styling my categorical data with shapes.

Basic thought outline for styling:
Multiple site revisits   - point displacemet
Continuous CPUE data     - graduated color scales
Categorical season data  - different marker shapes (problem here!).